# requestCastDeviceForRoute in onRouteAdded

Tags: google-cast

I'm developing app for Chromecast. I'v tried Android Sample from https://github.com/googlecast/cast-android-sample, and he works fine - I may click on Cast icon, select device and start streaming. So, MediaRouter.Callback looks like this:

```
private class MyMediaRouterCallback extends MediaRouter.Callback {
    @Override
    public void onRouteSelected(MediaRouter router, RouteInfo route) {
        MediaRouteHelper.requestCastDeviceForRoute(route);
    }
}
```

And it works. But I want to start streaming on my device without stream button. So I'v changed this callback to:

```
private class MyMediaRouterCallback extends MediaRouter.Callback {
    @Override
    public void  onRouteAdded (MediaRouter router, RouteInfo route)
        MediaRouteHelper.requestCastDeviceForRoute(route);
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work. This callback fires, requestCastDeviceForRoute returns true with required device (I see it by route.getName()), but onDeviceAvailable from CastSampleActivity never called. I'v tried delayed call of requestCastDeviceForRoute using Handler.postDelayed, and still nothing.

So, how to use requestCastDeviceForRoute properly to stream on Chromecast device without Media Button, right after he will be detected in MediaRouter.Callback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try calling

```
mediaRouter.selectRoute(route);
```

instead of using the MediaRouterHelper. This has worked for me when calling from within `onRouteAdded()`

Comment: Works fine! I'v added selectRoute in onRouteAdded and now call MediaRouteHelper.requestCastDeviceForRoute from onRouteSelected. And onDeviceAvailable called successfully! Great solution, thanks!

Comment: Confirmed, but don't have 15 reputation points to vote. Sorry. When I earn 15 points - I will vote.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure I understand your question, are you trying to start streaming automatically as soon as the system "discovers" a cast device, without user clicking on the cast icon and selecting the device? Or are you trying to start streaming of the media immediately after user clicks on the cast icon and selects a target (i.e. removing the need to click on the Play button)?

Comment: The first one: "start streaming automatically as soon as the system "discovers" a cast device"

Comment: Yes, first one. And the answer by @AlonBurg helped me.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended flow is to let user choose the device manually, so what you are trying to do breaks the flow completely. What would user expect to happen if there is more than one chromecast device on the network? So it is strongly recommended not to go down that route.

Comment: Let's suppose we want to apply this only in the case it detects one route. Why does calling `MediaRouteHelper.requestCastDeviceForRoute(route)` from within onRouteAdded() doesn't work the same as when calling from onRouteSelected(). Are there any plans to publish the SDK source?

Comment: Yes, I'm breaking the flow. But this app is not intended for public access. It is for the clients of our company, and they want to see immediately broadcast on the TV simultaneously with the start of the application, without any further action. Anyway, thanks for recommendation.